# Throwing the status exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a `core` module that has such relationships

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
```

in service in method I would like to throw an exception (or otherwise) from the status code (for example, NOT FOUND 404) in case the user is not found.

```
getById(Long id) {
     //if the user with specified id does not exist

     //for example, cast an exception throw new UserNotFoundException(new List<FieldError>); with a list of error fields
    }
```

the problem is that this module has no dependency

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
```

and cannot use objects such as `ResponseEntity` or `HttpStatus`.

I want to achieve a result such as that here https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/src/main/java/com/service/app/rest/controller/advice/ErrorFieldsExceptionHandler.java, but without `org.springframework.web`.

I could be advised on how I can throw an exception with the status and error list object as response?

Comment: Status `404 NOT FOUND` is basically a HTTP status code, if you want something like this but without `org.springframework.web` then what kind of frameworks you're used to handle the servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Let's exercise the good old [Single Responsibility Principle](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html).

The *Service* layer is not concerned about HTTP STATUS. Throwing some sort of `HttpStatus404Exception` from the *Service* layer is not a good choice. How about if someone wants to use the *Service* layer in a batch processor which connects directly to the database? In this case the `HttpStatus404Exception` is totally out of place.

Throw a `UserNotFoundException` (which could extend a `NotFoundException`) and let the *Controller* layer (in your case a *WebController* layer) handle the exceptions gracefully.